# read and write a bmp file in c++

Tags: c++

i am trying to read and write a bmp file in c++.output file is created but is not opening and it's size is  257kb whereas the input file is 258kb.i first read and write the 14 byte header file,40 byte imageheader file,then the 512*512 pixels,here's my code,can anyone help please

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
ifstream iFile;
char ch;
iFile.open("lena.bmp",ios::binary);
ofstream oFile;
oFile.open("lena3.bmp",ios::binary);
//int headerImageHeader=54;
// int imageHeader=40;
int fs[54];
//int ihs[imageHeader];
int tfs[54];

int pixel[512][512];
if(iFile.is_open() && oFile.is_open())
{
   for(int i=0;i<54;i++)
    {
        iFile.get(ch);
        fs[i]=ch;
        cout<<fs[i]<<"  ";
        char p;
        p=fs[i];
        oFile<<p;

    }

for(int w=0;w<512;w++)
    {
        for(int h=0;h<512;h++)
        {
            iFile.get(ch);
            pixel[w][h]=ch;
            //cout<<pixel[w][h]<<;
            char pi=pixel[w][h];
            oFile<<pi;
        }
    }
   oFile.close();
   iFile.close();

}

else cout << "Unable to open file"<<endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why don't you read bitmap header as a single struct? Width and height calculation with double pow is insane. Just like extracting chars from file using `get`. Also `int fs[headerImageHeader];` and `int pixel[width][height];` are not standard as array sizes are not a compile-time constant.

Comment: Are you trying to learn how to work with bmp? If you not then just use a binary reader/writer

Comment: You should output a line ending after `cout << "Unable to open file";` -> `cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl;`

Comment: @SurvivalMachine, actually, you shouldn't use `std::endl` unless you want to force a flush. Otherwise, just use `\n`.

Comment: Get a hex-editor and become familiar with it. Once this is done, you'll be able to see for yourself where the expected (required) output and that actually produced differ. It then becomes a trivial exercise to see where the problem in the output is. From there you alter the code such that it produces the necessary output.

Comment: This looks like 8-bit bitmap, it will include a pallet which you cannot ignore. Each pixel is one byte (8 bit) so it can be read as a single `char`. But you convert `char` to `int` and back to `char`. Why?  Also you should use `fstream::read/write` to work with binary data. `get` and `put` will do but stay away from `>>` and `<<` operator when working with binary data. I don't know what's the point of this question so I won't bother writing an answer. You should use a library to work with bitmaps, for example Window standard GDI functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple problems. Basically, the pixel storage in BMP file is not that simple. It depends on the type of BMP (e.g. `Monochrome Bitmap`, `16 Color Bitmap`, `256 Color Bitmap` and `24-bit Bitmap` etc).

There are two options to read one Bitmap file and write it in another Bitmap file.
a) Read each byte from the source file and write in destination file
b) Understand `Bitmap` storage format and write code accordingly.

For option `b)` good source is available at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

In summary, the calculation of Pixel Array storage (size) is:

```
PixelArraySize = RowSize x ImageHeight
```

Where `ImageHeight` is height of image in pixel. The RowSize is calculated as:

```
RowSize = [(BitsPerPixelxImageWidth + 31) / 32 ]x4
```